# Can I email a single page of a MS Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, email

I have a Microsoft Word document 50 pages long. I want to email a single page of the document. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Copy the single page and mail it? What issue are you having?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done without creating an intermediary file with the pages you require to send. Some VBA scripts around to automate this, but you'd need to investigate yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer to your question is, no it cannot be done directly from your email client because your email client (Outlook, Gmail, Mac Mail, others) do not have a direct interface into a Microsoft Word document.

With that said, if you are using a Windows version of Outlook, then there would be a possibility of writing a special VBA macro to do it, but then it could not be a generic macro that worked correctly in all cases. This is because in a Microsoft Word document, there is no such thing as a static and addressable page. In MS Word, pages are dynamically defined by margins, fonts, spacing, print drivers, etc.

If you need to provide the content of a certain page in a Word document to someone else so they can edit it, your best bet would be to paste the content into a separate document that you email. This of course does not give you the header/footer content. If you just want someone to view the content, then make a screenshot of the page and mail that.